# For valid DateTime(Error shows string was not recognized )

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, types, casting

I am trying to convert my string formated value to date type with format dd/MM/yyyy.  It runs fine but when I enter fromdate(dd/MM/yyyy) in textbox its fine and todate(dd/MM/yyyy) in textbox  then it gives an error that string was not recognized as a valid datetime.What is the problem exactly i dont know. same code run on another appliction its run fine but in my application it shows Error.

Below I have used array for required format and split also used.

```
string fromdate = punchin.ToString();
string[] arrfromdate = fromdate.Split('/');
fromdate = arrfromdate[1].ToString() + "/" + arrfromdate[0].ToString() + "/" + arrfromdate[2].ToString();
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse(fromdate.ToString());
```

Comment: what u are getting in string fromdate

Comment: What are you doing in the third line ? post a sample string contained in `punchin`

Comment: My guess is that it's trying to parse MM/dd/yyyy instead, and your to-date is `13/01/2000` or something. You could use `DateTime.ParseExact` to enforce your format.

Comment: Thank you Rajeev Kumar. I got 5/13/2013 12:21:35 PM in string fromdate

Comment: I'm guessing he, in the description, has swapped the days with the month in the format string.
OP, you need to use formatstring on order to parse datetime,

Comment: Thank you Habib I am doing in third line Conversion of date format instead of  this format MM/dd/yyyy  to dd//MM/yyyy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got 5/13/2013 12:21:35 PM in string fromdate

Use [DateTime.TryParseExac](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9s47fcc.aspx)t, You **don't have to split** your string based on `/` and then get first three items from the array instead you can simply do:

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("5/13/2013 12:21:35 PM",
                                  "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                  DateTimeStyles.None,
                                  out dt))
{
    //date is fine
}
```

Using single `d` and single `M` as it can accomodate single digit as well as double digits day/Month part. **You can simply pass `punchin` as the string parameter, Calling `ToString` on string types is redundant.**

Comment: It shows error like this The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @user2131469, replace it with `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or just right click on it and select `Resolve`

Answer (score 2):

try with [**`DateTime.TryParseExact`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) as below

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputText, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out date))
{
   // Success
}
```

if you know the format of input date time you don't need to do any string manipulation. 
But you need to give correct [Date and Time Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
DateTime.ParseExact(fromdate, "MM/dd/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Obviously you can reformat the above, and use different providers by creating an instance of CultureInfo related to the string you are parsing, and you can modify the format string to reflect that culture or to accommodate more date parts

Comment: Thank you Segev -CJ- Shmueli. Here what is the CultureInfo, it shows error like this The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Add reference to `System.Globalization`